# java generating numbers without repetition without arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, shuffle

I know the usual way of shuffling of Array-list;
is there another way of mimicking what shuffle does for Array (NOT Lists) ?
I already code something that works with `rand.NextInt` and `IF` and `while`;
but I highly doubt that is the most efficient way.
any Idea considering low resources?

this is what Ive got; but I doubt the efficiency:

```
       static int[] order = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
       static int[] order2 = new int[] {0,0,0,0,0};
       static int p;
        Random rand = new Random(); 
    int m=global.order[rand.nextInt( global.order.length)];
    global.order2[m]=m;

    int n=global.order[rand.nextInt( global.order.length)];
    while ( m==n )  { n=global.order[rand.nextInt( global.order.length)];}
    global.order2[n]=n;

    int o=global.order[rand.nextInt( global.order.length)];

    while (m==o || n==o) { o=global.order[rand.nextInt( global.order.length)]; }
    global.order2[o]=o;
    for (int y=1; y<=4; y++){
        if (global.order2[y]!=m && global.order2[y]!=n && global.order2[y]!=o){
            global.order2[y]=y;
            global.p=y;
```

Comment: I don't understand at all what you're trying to ask.

Comment: What's your goal? and why is `Collections.shuffle()` not good enought?

Comment: do you want an array of random numbers with no duplicate entries? Like a set?

Comment: say we have have a array{1,2,3,4} ; how do you shuffle it in most efficient way; without casting it to list ?

Comment: @robbmj I already have the set; I want to shuffle it. without casting it

Comment: @Elist because I have to cast from Array

Comment: And it has to be an array not a collection

Comment: You said you already coded something that works - I'd probably stick with that, or use an `ArrayList` and `Collections.shuffle()`. Unless you're using massive arrays, I don't think you'd notice any performance issues.

Comment: @parkovski do you have any thing to assure me about perfomance of casting in this case; all I know is to avoid it

Comment: @Shervin4030 Please show us what you have so far. Many people will be more glad to help you if they know you've tried something yourself first.

Comment: Please spell-check and format your code more carefully next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Fisher-Yates shuffle ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle))

You can easily follow this guideline to create your own Java implementation:

1. Pick a random integer `r` from the range `[0..array.length)`
2. Swap `array[0]` and `array[r]`
3. Pick a new random integer `r` from the range `[1..array.length)`
4. Swap `array[1]` and `array[r]`

and so on. This translates fairly easily to a loop. The performance is good, there's no need to reallocate the array or create new objects and execution time scales linearly.

Comment: @Shervin4030, yep! Fisher-Yates is actually what `Collections.shuffle` uses (although Java's own version goes in reverse, shuffling the `List` from end to start) but I understand your desire for a in-place array version as well.

Comment: is this the so called modern way of FY algorithm ? or the usual ?

Comment: @Shervin4030 IIRC "modern" means FY implementations that use swapping instead of copying, so yes, this is modern. Wikipedia's example of modern seems to go from end to beginning as well, but the direction (start to end vs end to start) isn't really crucial.

Comment: sometimes wikipedia is more like lostopedia; tnx I got what I needed

Comment: @Shervin4030, no prob, glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is an unsorted set with randomly generated values, consider using a HashSet.

To implement this with a normal array your insertions into the array will take `O(n)` time as you need to look at all the elements to see if it already contains the random number. Using a `HashSet` insertions will take `O(1)`. You can then convert it to an array.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class MakeUnsortedSet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

        while (set.size() < 10) {
            set.add((int)(Math.random() * 20)); 
        }

        Integer[] ints = new Integer[10];
        set.toArray(ints);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In essence, an `ArrayList` is just a regular array wraped up in `List` interface implementation. If you somewhat think you can come up with a better implementation to suit your performence needs, just implement your own `List` and pass it to `Collections.shuffle()`.

If you want to avoid instantiating a new object of your `List` implementation for every array, you could implement it in such way you can only replace the reference to the wraped array and make minor modifications.

Anyway, I would first look at `ArrayList`'s source code (and maybe `extends` it) before trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: there has to be a non troubling way

Comment: I guess the most non troubling way would be to pass your array to `ArrayList`'s constructor. Without deeply diving into the sourcecode I would guess this way is fairly cheap in performence, and is certainly the most easy one.